# root = tkinter.Tk() or root = Tk()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two scripts that both work:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.configure(bg='blue')
root.mainloop()
```

and

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello world!")
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I want to combine the two scripts to print the text on a blue background, but moving anything from one script to another seems to break it.

I can't figure out if it's about `root = tkinter.Tk()` vs `root = Tk()`, or `import tkinter` vs `from tkinter import *`, or something entirely different. I can't find a successful combination.

I'm using Ubuntu and Python 3.6.9.

Comment: Both should be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use two different styles when importing tkinter, you will need to modify the code from one file when moving to the other. The code in your first example is the preferred way to do it because [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) discourages wildcard imports.

When when you copy the code from the second example, you'll need to add `tkinter.` to every tkinter command (`tkinter.Tk()`, `tkinter.Text(root)`, `tk.INSERT`, etc.

Personally I find `import tkinter as tk` to be a slight improvement. I find `tk.Tk()` to be a little easier to type and read than `tkinter.Tk()`.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I wanted Label rather than Text:

import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='blue')
label = tk.Label(root, text= "Hello world!")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()

Answer (score 1):

You should know that:

```
from tkinter import *
```

will import all the attribute in the `tkinter`.But if you also define some variable in your script.It will be covered by your new variable.So we don't recommend you to use that.(If you used both `from tkinter.ttk import *` and `from tkinter import *`.Some default widgets of tkinter will be covered by `ttk` widgets.)

Just like Mr.Bryan said,I'd like to use `import tkinter as tk`,too.